# Why highcharts for the reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

I was wondering why the [highcharts library](http://www.highcharts.com/) is being used as the graph library for the reputation page.
Why use a commercial library when there are good open source alternatives like [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) or others available?

Comment: It used to use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), iirc.

Comment: Not everything has to be open source

Comment: I think buying a commercial or donating to open source, not so different for them?