# What graphing library is used for the new reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

The new reputation graph is really nice! What library is used to render it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the question [that was asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85241/why-highcharts-for-the-reputation-graph), the new one uses the Highcharts library, which has a site here: http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Confirmed by viewing the source.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/Js/third-party/highcharts.js"></script>
`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @Bill!